# How to reflectively get existing properties from a dynamic proxy

Tags: c#, dynamic, proxy

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

class Bar: Foo
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Bar2: Foo
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a 3rd party control that takes a List and displays the contents of the list. It looks at the type of the first object in the List and assumes that all the following items are of the same type. This means that the List I provide must either be all Bar instances or all Bar2 instances, because if it contains a mix of Bar and Bar2 then the control will throw an error when it tries to reflectively access a property on the wrong type (whether that type contains the property or not).

My team lead has directed me along the path of creating a dynamic proxy. I understand that a dynamic proxy could resolve attempts to access unknown properties at runtime and provide default values, but what I don't see is how an existing 3rd party control like the one we already have in place could figure out what properties are available.

The idea my team lead has is that the dynamic proxy could aggregate the properties on Bar and Bar2 so that the 3rd party control would see (in this example) both the Text and the Value properties, but the proxy would just return null for either property if it's being accessed on the class that doesn't contain it. While this sounds great in theory, I can't make the existing 3rd party control call some special GetAllTheAvailableProperties() method that I create. It is, of course, going to just use reflection to figure out what the properties are.

I know there are several dynamic proxy libraries out there. Would any of them help with this problem, or is there a way I could implement a dynamic object in such a way that I could make it return a custom list of properties when a 3rd party control reflectively queries for available properties?

The answer seems to be an obvious no, but I just want to make sure. I'm afraid my team lead may be trying to put a square peg into a round hole here, but nonetheless if there's a way that I could implement a solution the way he has envisioned and make him feel like a genius in the process then that would really be ideal.

Comment: It sounds like a band-aid across your potential test suite for this piece of code. Third-party library doesn't accept certain input? Abstract it away and guard against it. Then you can have tests that enforce it. You're programming around your other developers passing invalid input into this control - a huge waste of time IMO.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I can't really disagree. The issue arose because there are certain properties that aren't always used by an object, and there are certain rules on what values that can be placed in these properties. Instead of just coding these validation rules into the one object, he felt we needed 4 derived classes to represent the "real-world" counterparts in order to adequately protect the database from getting populated with bad data.